# Will an redirect setup in IIS 6 work for a form POST?

Tags: iis, post, redirect, iis-6

I have a website where a third party performs an HTTP post to a file - let's call it `http://mywebsite/third-party-post.cfm` (it's a ColdFusion website).

I want to move the code to a new file - let's call it `http://mywebsite/third-party-post-new.cfm`.

If I change the file attributes in IIS:

[image: IIS File Properties Window]

Will this pass the form fields for a POST action, or does a redirect like this work only for GET?

Comment: FYI, I just ran a test in IIS 7.5 and the form parameters were NOT passed to the redirect page. Is this possible in IIS 6?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass post parameters during the redirect. The web server actually makes a call back to the browser to ask it if it can move the page, the browser then resubmits a request to the URL the server is asking to move it to. This is I believe a 301 call to the browser.You never see this and it happens in milliseconds. When the redirect happens it will destroy any post parameters that were submitted in favor of the new request coming from your browser, the server will see it as a brand new request with no post data.

You will need to pass your data in some other way to the page, either through a GET request or a include of the script you wish to run on the old page.

you might be better off actually using a URL rewrite to change how the web server sees a request for that given page.

```
the apache script would look something like this

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase    /

RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule   ^third-party-post.cfm /third-party-post-new.cfm [L,QSA]
```

The above code will take a request for the orignal page and translate it to a request for the new page. If will still maintain the original URL though but will display the new page.
IIS has a URLrewrite function you can utilize or if you are familiar with Htaccess and apache, you can use a Helicon Ape http://www.helicontech.com/ape/ to read htaccess files for your site.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I may try a URLRewrite rule, but that might not be the best idea for maintenance. I think the best option at this point is to contact the vendor and have them change the URL they are posting to.

Answer (score 0):

See post https://stackoverflow.com/a/13628908/2482184. Although this question is about apache the same is true for IIS no matter which version you are using. There are many other options available to bypass this issue. One of them is to create the /third-party-post.cfm file and include the /third-party-post-new.cfm. You can even use a new HTML5 technique to change the url without refreshing the page (see http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/ ).