# php session data lost after login possible error in htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

After user logs in, data is posted into login_db.php file consisting of the following code which checks the login and stores it into session variables. Depending on login type the `self.location` line takes it to irrespective location.

In each location1.php, location2.php, and location3.php `session_start` is written in first line of each file.

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    extract($_POST);
    include_once 'login/utils/conn.php';

    if(isset($_POST['login']))
    { 
         $name = $_POST['name'];
         $password = $_POST['password'];
         $sql = "SELECT ad_pk,ad_uname,ad_pwd,ad_type FROM adminlogin WHERE ad_uname ='$name' AND ad_pwd ='$password'";
         $result = mysql_query($sql);

         if($res = mysql_fetch_array($result))
         {  
            //print_r($_POST);exit;
            if ($res["ad_type"] == 'telecall') 
            {
                $_SESSION["ad_uname"] = $res["ad_type"];
                $_SESSION["adminid"] = $res["ad_pk"];
                echo $dt=date("Y-m-d",time());
                $pk=$res['ad_pk'];
                $uk=$res['ad_uname'];
                echo  $sql_ins_log = "insert into login_info(user_id,user_name,login_date)values('$pk','$uk','$dt')";
                $result_log = mysql_query($sql_ins_log);
                echo "<script>self.location='location1.php';</script>";
            }
            else if ( $res["ad_type"] == 'admin') 
            {
                $_SESSION["ad_uname"] = $res["ad_type"];
                $_SESSION["adminid"] = $res["ad_pk"];
                echo $dt=date("Y-m-d",time());
                $pk=$res['ad_pk'];
                $uk=$res['ad_uname'];
                echo  $sql_ins_log = "insert into login_info(user_id,user_name,login_date)values('$pk','$uk','$dt')";
                $result_log = mysql_query($sql_ins_log);
                echo "<script>self.location='location2.php';</script>";

            }
            else if ( $res["ad_type"] == 'bussuser') 
            {
                   $_SESSION["ad_uname"] = $res["ad_type"];
                   $_SESSION["adminid"] = $res["ad_pk"];
                   echo $dt=date("Y-m-d",time());
                   $pk=$res['ad_pk'];
                   $uk=$res['ad_uname'];
                   echo  $sql_ins_log = "insert into login_info(user_id,user_name,login_date)values('$pk','$uk','$dt')";
                   $result_log = mysql_query($sql_ins_log);
                   echo "<script>self.location='location3.php';</script>";
            }
            else
            {
                    echo "<script>alert('Incorrect username or password');self.location='login.php';</script>";
            } 
        } 
    }
    ?>

    Here i can see session data on print_r($_SESSION);

    After self.location is executed control goes to 3 different pages. At the start of page the session_start line is written. Still the session data is lost and Access denied message is displayed on login.


    <?
    session_start();
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING);
    //echo "helllooo".$_SESSION["ad_uname"];
    print_r($_SESSION);// line returns empty array

    if($_SESSION["ad_uname"]=='telecall')// if type of logged in user telecall show a different form
    {
    ?>
       // some form displayed and further actions executed.
    <? 
    } 
    else
    {
       echo "<script>alert('Access Denied');self.location='login.php';</script>";
    }
    ?>

    The session id seems to change.. dont know why.can anyone guide me where i am going wrong? and why is the session_id returning 2 different ids on the login_db.php file and the location1/2/3.php files?
```

Now I have an `.htaccess` file (purpose to remove the `.php` extension in url except for posting data from files, hence the line: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =POST`) which contains following code: which when removed session works successfully..

The htaccess needs to remove .php extension but then not affect the session or posting of data.

I am new to writing the htaccess code . hence need guidance why my htaccess is contradicting and clearing session and creating two different session id's. Help will make my day. :)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =POST
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. You should read on [how to prevent them in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114).

Answer (score 0):

POST data is discarded on redirect as a client will perform a GET request to the URL specified by the 301

[Similar question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13628831/apache-301-redirect-and-preserving-post-data) which suggests the below,

One option is to catch POST requests to the url to be redirected and pass it off to a page to handle the redirect. You'd need to do the transposition of the parameters in code then issue the redirect header with the parameter appended new url that way.

[W3C reference about how 301 redirect works](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

Comment: and how am i to redirected and pass it off to a page to handle the redirect.?? i m finding it confusing.

Comment: did u mean to add rewrite rule as such in htaccess??
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L]
with R=307

Comment: Not sure about 307 redirect. The 307 would probably work in a similar fashion as 301.