# Why is HTML POST form interpreted as GET when using an absolute URL?

Tags: apache, http-post, forms

I was writing a test HTML form locally, invoking a distant webpage in the `action` field.  However I figured that though set as POST, the form would only send GET data.  I moved it on the distant server, but it behaved the same way.  Then I changed the absolute URL to a relative one and it worked.

Is it expected, or is there some server setting to change this behaviour ?

Here is an almost minimal form reproducing the issue :

```
<form action="http://example.com/foobar.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="blah">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

For testing purposes foobar.php could contain

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']; ?>
```

Edit : There *must* be something wrong with my setup, since I can find loads of similar and supposedly working samples on the web (and actually this is what I am supposed to achieve at the end).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, this is because [POST data is discarded on 301 Permanent Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13628908/812102), and I was using a ServerAlias with RedirectMatch 301.

A solution could be [to use 307 Temporary Redirect](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/99966/97226) but I think I will just stick to the main ServerName.