# Nginx loses POST variable with http -> https redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, nginx, https

I have a website set up that uses the redirect method...

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.org;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

However when a page is posted to "http://example.com" it redirects to "https://example.com" and in the process, it strips the POST.

I recognize this is how it works, however I need to somehow do one of the following...

- Do a redirect from http -> https while keeping the POST variable intact
- Convert the POST variable to a GET variable during the redirect (which would work fine)
- Redirect everything EXCEPT for one folder

Any suggestions? I'm a bit lost...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are willing to forgo the "permanent" redirect status, I believe a 307 redirect instead of a 301 will preserve the POST. There actually is a redirect that is permanent and preserves the post, a 308, but it isn't well adopted yet by browsers and other user agents.

Answer (score 4):

A 308 redirect is a fix, but the solution is to POST directly to https:

- by posting to http, your post data are not secure
- the redirect make the process slower
- if you post to http from an https webpage, browser may display a warning to the user

Comment: Definitely would prefer to do this... unfortunately the issue is that it's an OLD flash swf file (an online course) that posts to the http/:80 url, and unfortunately I have no control over it. I fixed it by using a 308/307 rather than 301. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is a common problem and there is not an easy solution for this.

There are some answers with similar questions here

[Apache 301 Redirect and preserving post data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13628831/apache-301-redirect-and-preserving-post-data)

[Is it possible to redirect post data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358263/is-it-possible-to-redirect-post-data)

Maybe one of the answers could help to solve your issue