# Nginx POST requests turns GET

Tags: node.js, nginx, redirect

I redirect all of the requests to HTTPS with this snippet:

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
```

}

The problem is that I can not send a POST request to my server thru Nginx because it redirects to a GET request.

I use NodeJS and Express.

Comment: The POST is already insecure, you need to make it to https to start with. There's some discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39280361/3001761.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/312111/how-do-i-get-nginx-to-forward-http-post-requests-via-rewrite

Comment: Why do you send post request via http if your server use https?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nginx loses POST variable with http -> https redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39280361/nginx-loses-post-variable-with-http-https-redirect)

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to forget the "permanent" redirect status, I believe a 307 redirect instead of a 301 will preserve the POST.