# TYK for POST params

Tags: tyk

I had successfully created an API for GET but failed to do it for POST.
The var1 and var2 in this screenshot should not be null. Please help.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue is when I redirected my server from HTTP to HTTPS thru 301, post data are dropped.

[Apache 301 Redirect and preserving post data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13628831/apache-301-redirect-and-preserving-post-data)