# Sparql POST query using HTTP.jl

Tags: julia

I am trying to query the UK Open Geography Portal using their sparql endpoint.

ChatGPT tells me that the following code is correct and even tells me the JSON response I should get. The response it offers is incorrect and so, it seems, is the advice about the code. The response is `Bad request. Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.`

I know the query itself is OK because I can run it in python using SPARQLWrapper.

What have I done wrong?

```
using HTTP, JSON
query = """
        PREFIX pcd: <http://statistics.data.gov.uk/def/postcode/unit#>
        PREFIX geog: <http://statistics.data.gov.uk/def/hierarchy/best-fit#>
        PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
        PREFIX stge: <http://statistics.data.gov.uk/def/statistical-geography#>
        SELECT ?display ?ward ?la ?pcon ?reg ?dintr ?dterm
        WHERE
        {
            ?s rdf:type <http://statistics.data.gov.uk/def/postcode/unit> .
            ?s pcd:postcode1space ?display .
            filter(?display in ("OX17 2JP"))
            ?s geog:ward ?wardcode ;
                geog:europeanelectoralregion ?regcode ;
                geog:localauthoritydistrict ?lacode ;
                geog:parliamentaryconstituency ?pconcode .
            OPTIONAL {?s <http://statistics.data.gov.uk/def/postcode/unit/dateofintroduction> ?dintr ;
                        <http://statistics.data.gov.uk/def/postcode/unit/dateoftermination> ?dterm .}
            ?wardcode stge:officialname ?ward .
            ?lacode stge:officialname ?la .
            ?pconcode stge:officialname ?pcon .
            ?regcode stge:officialname ?reg .
        }
        LIMIT 1000
        """
url = raw"http://statistics.data.gov.uk/sparql"
response = HTTP.post(url, ["query" => query])
ret = JSON.parse(String(response.body))
```

When I run this code in VSCode, I get:

```
"""
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
Content-Length: 273
Date: Thu, 26 Oct 2023 08:16:59 GMT


<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Bad Request</h1>
<h2>Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>
""")
Stacktrace:
  [1] (::HTTP.ConnectionRequest.var"#connections#4"{HTTP.ConnectionRequest.var"#connections#1#5"{HTTP.TimeoutRequest.var"#timeouts#3"{HTTP.TimeoutRequest.var"#timeouts#1#4"{HTTP.ExceptionRequest.var"#exceptions#2"{HTTP.ExceptionRequest.var"#exceptions#1#3"{typeof(HTTP.StreamRequest.streamlayer)}}}}}})(req::HTTP.Messages.Request; proxy::Nothing, socket_type::Type, socket_type_tls::Type, readtimeout::Int64, connect_timeout::Int64, logerrors::Bool, logtag::Nothing, kw::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Union{Nothing, Int64}, Tuple{Symbol, Symbol, Symbol}, NamedTuple{(:iofunction, :decompress, :verbose), Tuple{Nothing, Nothing, Int64}}})
    @ HTTP.ConnectionRequest C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\HTTP\SN7VW\src\clientlayers\ConnectionRequest.jl:144
  [2] (::Base.var"#90#92"{Base.var"#90#91#93"{ExponentialBackOff, HTTP.RetryRequest.var"#2#5"{Int64, typeof(HTTP.RetryRequest.FALSE), HTTP.Messages.Request, Base.RefValue{Int64}}, HTTP.ConnectionRequest.var"#connections#4"{HTTP.ConnectionRequest.var"#connections#1#5"{HTTP.TimeoutRequest.var"#timeouts#3"{HTTP.TimeoutRequest.var"#timeouts#1#4"{HTTP.ExceptionRequest.var"#exceptions#2"{HTTP.ExceptionRequest.var"#exceptions#1#3"{typeof(HTTP.StreamRequest.streamlayer)}}}}}}}})(args::HTTP.Messages.Request; kwargs::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Union{Nothing, Int64}, Tuple{Symbol, Symbol, Symbol}, NamedTuple{(:iofunction, :decompress, :verbose), Tuple{Nothing, Nothing, Int64}}})
    @ Base .\error.jl:296
  [3] (::HTTP.RetryRequest.var"#manageretries#3"{HTTP.RetryRequest.var"#manageretries#1#4"{HTTP.ConnectionRequest.var"#connections#4"{HTTP.ConnectionRequest.var"#connections#1#5"{HTTP.TimeoutRequest.var"#timeouts#3"{HTTP.TimeoutRequest.var"#timeouts#1#4"{HTTP.ExceptionRequest.var"#exceptions#2"{HTTP.ExceptionRequest.var"#exceptions#1#3"{typeof(HTTP.StreamRequest.streamlayer)}}}}}}}})(req::HTTP.Messages.Request; retry::Bool, retries::Int64, retry_delays::ExponentialBackOff, retry_check::Function, retry_non_idempotent::Bool, kw::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Union{Nothing, Int64}, Tuple{Symbol, Symbol, Symbol}, NamedTuple{(:iofunction, :decompress, :verbose), Tuple{Nothing, Nothing, Int64}}})
    @ HTTP.RetryRequest C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\HTTP\SN7VW\src\clientlayers\RetryRequest.jl:75
  [4] manageretries
    @ C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\HTTP\SN7VW\src\clientlayers\RetryRequest.jl:30 [inlined]
  [5] (::HTTP.CookieRequest.var"#managecookies#4"{HTTP.CookieRequest.var"#managecookies#1#5"{HTTP.RetryRequest.var"#manageretries#3"{HTTP.RetryRequest.var"#manageretries#1#4"{HTTP.ConnectionRequest.var"#connections#4"{HTTP.ConnectionRequest.var"#connections#1#5"{HTTP.TimeoutRequest.var"#timeouts#3"{HTTP.TimeoutRequest.var"#timeouts#1#4"{HTTP.ExceptionRequest.var"#exceptions#2"{HTTP.ExceptionRequest.var"#exceptions#1#3"{typeof(HTTP.StreamRequest.streamlayer)}}}}}}}}}})(req::HTTP.Messages.Request; cookies::Bool, cookiejar::HTTP.Cookies.CookieJar, kw::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Union{Nothing, Int64}, Tuple{Symbol, Symbol, Symbol}, NamedTuple{(:iofunction, :decompress, :verbose), Tuple{Nothing, Nothing, Int64}}})
    @ HTTP.CookieRequest C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\HTTP\SN7VW\src\clientlayers\CookieRequest.jl:42
  [6] managecookies
    @ C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\HTTP\SN7VW\src\clientlayers\CookieRequest.jl:19 [inlined]
  [7] (::HTTP.HeadersRequest.var"#defaultheaders#2"{HTTP.HeadersRequest.var"#defaultheaders#1#3"{HTTP.CookieRequest.var"#managecookies#4"{HTTP.CookieRequest.var"#managecookies#1#5"{HTTP.RetryRequest.var"#manageretries#3"{HTTP.RetryRequest.var"#manageretries#1#4"{HTTP.ConnectionRequest.var"#connections#4"{HTTP.ConnectionRequest.var"#connections#1#5"{HTTP.TimeoutRequest.var"#timeouts#3"{HTTP.TimeoutRequest.var"#timeouts#1#4"{HTTP.ExceptionRequest.var"#exceptions#2"{HTTP.ExceptionRequest.var"#exceptions#1#3"{typeof(HTTP.StreamRequest.streamlayer)}}}}}}}}}}}})(req::HTTP.Messages.Request; iofunction::Nothing, decompress::Nothing, basicauth::Bool, detect_content_type::Bool, canonicalize_headers::Bool, kw::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Int64, Tuple{Symbol}, NamedTuple{(:verbose,), Tuple{Int64}}})
    @ HTTP.HeadersRequest C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\HTTP\SN7VW\src\clientlayers\HeadersRequest.jl:71
  [8] defaultheaders
    @ C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\HTTP\SN7VW\src\clientlayers\HeadersRequest.jl:14 [inlined]
  [9] (::HTTP.RedirectRequest.var"#redirects#3"{HTTP.RedirectRequest.var"#redirects#1#4"{HTTP.HeadersRequest.var"#defaultheaders#2"{HTTP.HeadersRequest.var"#defaultheaders#1#3"{HTTP.CookieRequest.var"#managecookies#4"{HTTP.CookieRequest.var"#managecookies#1#5"{HTTP.RetryRequest.var"#manageretries#3"{HTTP.RetryRequest.var"#manageretries#1#4"{HTTP.ConnectionRequest.var"#connections#4"{HTTP.ConnectionRequest.var"#connections#1#5"{HTTP.TimeoutRequest.var"#timeouts#3"{HTTP.TimeoutRequest.var"#timeouts#1#4"{HTTP.ExceptionRequest.var"#exceptions#2"{HTTP.ExceptionRequest.var"#exceptions#1#3"{typeof(HTTP.StreamRequest.streamlayer)}}}}}}}}}}}}}})(req::HTTP.Messages.Request; redirect::Bool, redirect_limit::Int64, redirect_method::Nothing, forwardheaders::Bool, response_stream::Nothing, kw::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Int64, Tuple{Symbol}, NamedTuple{(:verbose,), Tuple{Int64}}})
    @ HTTP.RedirectRequest C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\HTTP\SN7VW\src\clientlayers\RedirectRequest.jl:25
 [10] redirects
    @ C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\HTTP\SN7VW\src\clientlayers\RedirectRequest.jl:14 [inlined]
 [11] (::HTTP.MessageRequest.var"#makerequest#3"{HTTP.MessageRequest.var"#makerequest#1#4"{HTTP.RedirectRequest.var"#redirects#3"{HTTP.RedirectRequest.var"#redirects#1#4"{HTTP.HeadersRequest.var"#defaultheaders#2"{HTTP.HeadersRequest.var"#defaultheaders#1#3"{HTTP.CookieRequest.var"#managecookies#4"{HTTP.CookieRequest.var"#managecookies#1#5"{HTTP.RetryRequest.var"#manageretries#3"{HTTP.RetryRequest.var"#manageretries#1#4"{HTTP.ConnectionRequest.var"#connections#4"{HTTP.ConnectionRequest.var"#connections#1#5"{HTTP.TimeoutRequest.var"#timeouts#3"{HTTP.TimeoutRequest.var"#timeouts#1#4"{HTTP.ExceptionRequest.var"#exceptions#2"{HTTP.ExceptionRequest.var"#exceptions#1#3"{typeof(HTTP.StreamRequest.streamlayer)}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}})(method::String, url::URIs.URI, headers::Vector{Pair{String, String}}, body::Vector{UInt8}; copyheaders::Bool, response_stream::Nothing, http_version::HTTP.Strings.HTTPVersion, verbose::Int64, kw::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
    @ HTTP.MessageRequest C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\HTTP\SN7VW\src\clientlayers\MessageRequest.jl:35
 [12] makerequest
    @ C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\HTTP\SN7VW\src\clientlayers\MessageRequest.jl:24 [inlined]
 [13] request(stack::HTTP.MessageRequest.var"#makerequest#3"{HTTP.MessageRequest.var"#makerequest#1#4"{HTTP.RedirectRequest.var"#redirects#3"{HTTP.RedirectRequest.var"#redirects#1#4"{HTTP.HeadersRequest.var"#defaultheaders#2"{HTTP.HeadersRequest.var"#defaultheaders#1#3"{HTTP.CookieRequest.var"#managecookies#4"{HTTP.CookieRequest.var"#managecookies#1#5"{HTTP.RetryRequest.var"#manageretries#3"{HTTP.RetryRequest.var"#manageretries#1#4"{HTTP.ConnectionRequest.var"#connections#4"{HTTP.ConnectionRequest.var"#connections#1#5"{HTTP.TimeoutRequest.var"#timeouts#3"{HTTP.TimeoutRequest.var"#timeouts#1#4"{HTTP.ExceptionRequest.var"#exceptions#2"{HTTP.ExceptionRequest.var"#exceptions#1#3"{typeof(HTTP.StreamRequest.streamlayer)}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}, method::String, url::String, h::Vector{Pair{String, String}}, b::Vector{UInt8}, q::Nothing; headers::Vector{Pair{String, String}}, body::Vector{UInt8}, query::Nothing, kw::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
    @ HTTP C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\HTTP\SN7VW\src\HTTP.jl:457
 [14] request(stack::Function, method::String, url::String, h::Vector{Pair{String, String}}, b::Vector{UInt8}, q::Nothing)
    @ HTTP C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\HTTP\SN7VW\src\HTTP.jl:455
 [15] #request#20
    @ C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\HTTP\SN7VW\src\HTTP.jl:315 [inlined]
 [16] request
    @ C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\HTTP\SN7VW\src\HTTP.jl:313 [inlined]
 [17] request(method::String, url::String, h::Vector{Pair{String, String}})
    @ HTTP C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\HTTP\SN7VW\src\HTTP.jl:313
 [18] post(::String, ::Vararg{Any}; kw::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
    @ HTTP C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\HTTP\SN7VW\src\HTTP.jl:532
 [19] post(::String, ::Vararg{Any})
    @ HTTP C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\HTTP\SN7VW\src\HTTP.jl:532
 [20] top-level scope
    @ c:\Users\TGebbels\OneDrive - ...\HTTPsparql.jl:46
in expression starting at c:\Users\TGebbels\OneDrive - ...\HTTPsparql.jl:46

caused by: HTTP.Exceptions.StatusError(400, "POST", "/sparql", HTTP.Messages.Response:
"""
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
Content-Length: 273
Date: Thu, 26 Oct 2023 08:16:59 GMT


<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Bad Request</h1>
<h2>Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>
""")
Stacktrace:
  [1] (::HTTP.ExceptionRequest.var"#exceptions#2"{HTTP.ExceptionRequest.var"#exceptions#1#3"{typeof(HTTP.StreamRequest.streamlayer)}})(stream::HTTP.Streams.Stream{HTTP.Messages.Response, HTTP.Connections.Connection{Sockets.TCPSocket}}; status_exception::Bool, timedout::Nothing, logerrors::Bool, logtag::Nothing, kw::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Union{Nothing, Int64}, Tuple{Symbol, Symbol, Symbol}, NamedTuple{(:iofunction, :decompress, :verbose), Tuple{Nothing, Nothing, Int64}}})
    @ HTTP.ExceptionRequest C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\HTTP\SN7VW\src\clientlayers\ExceptionRequest.jl:19
  [2] exceptions
    @ C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\HTTP\SN7VW\src\clientlayers\ExceptionRequest.jl:13 [inlined]
  [3] (::HTTP.TimeoutRequest.var"#timeouts#3"{HTTP.TimeoutRequest.var"#timeouts#1#4"{HTTP.ExceptionRequest.var"#exceptions#2"{HTTP.ExceptionRequest.var"#exceptions#1#3"{typeof(HTTP.StreamRequest.streamlayer)}}}})(stream::HTTP.Streams.Stream{HTTP.Messages.Response, HTTP.Connections.Connection{Sockets.TCPSocket}}; readtimeout::Int64, logerrors::Bool, logtag::Nothing, kw::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Union{Nothing, Int64}, Tuple{Symbol, Symbol, Symbol}, NamedTuple{(:iofunction, :decompress, :verbose), Tuple{Nothing, Nothing, Int64}}})
    @ HTTP.TimeoutRequest C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\HTTP\SN7VW\src\clientlayers\TimeoutRequest.jl:18
  [4] (::HTTP.ConnectionRequest.var"#connections#4"{HTTP.ConnectionRequest.var"#connections#1#5"{HTTP.TimeoutRequest.var"#timeouts#3"{HTTP.TimeoutRequest.var"#timeouts#1#4"{HTTP.ExceptionRequest.var"#exceptions#2"{HTTP.ExceptionRequest.var"#exceptions#1#3"{typeof(HTTP.StreamRequest.streamlayer)}}}}}})(req::HTTP.Messages.Request; proxy::Nothing, socket_type::Type, socket_type_tls::Type, readtimeout::Int64, connect_timeout::Int64, logerrors::Bool, logtag::Nothing, kw::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Union{Nothing, Int64}, Tuple{Symbol, Symbol, Symbol}, NamedTuple{(:iofunction, :decompress, :verbose), Tuple{Nothing, Nothing, Int64}}})
    @ HTTP.ConnectionRequest C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\HTTP\SN7VW\src\clientlayers\ConnectionRequest.jl:120
  [5] (::Base.var"#90#92"{Base.var"#90#91#93"{ExponentialBackOff, HTTP.RetryRequest.var"#2#5"{Int64, typeof(HTTP.RetryRequest.FALSE), HTTP.Messages.Request, Base.RefValue{Int64}}, HTTP.ConnectionRequest.var"#connections#4"{HTTP.ConnectionRequest.var"#connections#1#5"{HTTP.TimeoutRequest.var"#timeouts#3"{HTTP.TimeoutRequest.var"#timeouts#1#4"{HTTP.ExceptionRequest.var"#exceptions#2"{HTTP.ExceptionRequest.var"#exceptions#1#3"{typeof(HTTP.StreamRequest.streamlayer)}}}}}}}})(args::HTTP.Messages.Request; kwargs::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Union{Nothing, Int64}, Tuple{Symbol, Symbol, Symbol}, NamedTuple{(:iofunction, :decompress, :verbose), Tuple{Nothing, Nothing, Int64}}})
    @ Base .\error.jl:296
  [6] (::HTTP.RetryRequest.var"#manageretries#3"{HTTP.RetryRequest.var"#manageretries#1#4"{HTTP.ConnectionRequest.var"#connections#4"{HTTP.ConnectionRequest.var"#connections#1#5"{HTTP.TimeoutRequest.var"#timeouts#3"{HTTP.TimeoutRequest.var"#timeouts#1#4"{HTTP.ExceptionRequest.var"#exceptions#2"{HTTP.ExceptionRequest.var"#exceptions#1#3"{typeof(HTTP.StreamRequest.streamlayer)}}}}}}}})(req::HTTP.Messages.Request; retry::Bool, retries::Int64, retry_delays::ExponentialBackOff, retry_check::Function, retry_non_idempotent::Bool, kw::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Union{Nothing, Int64}, Tuple{Symbol, Symbol, Symbol}, NamedTuple{(:iofunction, :decompress, :verbose), Tuple{Nothing, Nothing, Int64}}})
    @ HTTP.RetryRequest C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\HTTP\SN7VW\src\clientlayers\RetryRequest.jl:75
  [7] manageretries
    @ C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\HTTP\SN7VW\src\clientlayers\RetryRequest.jl:30 [inlined]
  [8] (::HTTP.CookieRequest.var"#managecookies#4"{HTTP.CookieRequest.var"#managecookies#1#5"{HTTP.RetryRequest.var"#manageretries#3"{HTTP.RetryRequest.var"#manageretries#1#4"{HTTP.ConnectionRequest.var"#connections#4"{HTTP.ConnectionRequest.var"#connections#1#5"{HTTP.TimeoutRequest.var"#timeouts#3"{HTTP.TimeoutRequest.var"#timeouts#1#4"{HTTP.ExceptionRequest.var"#exceptions#2"{HTTP.ExceptionRequest.var"#exceptions#1#3"{typeof(HTTP.StreamRequest.streamlayer)}}}}}}}}}})(req::HTTP.Messages.Request; cookies::Bool, cookiejar::HTTP.Cookies.CookieJar, kw::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Union{Nothing, Int64}, Tuple{Symbol, Symbol, Symbol}, NamedTuple{(:iofunction, :decompress, :verbose), Tuple{Nothing, Nothing, Int64}}})
    @ HTTP.CookieRequest C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\HTTP\SN7VW\src\clientlayers\CookieRequest.jl:42
  [9] managecookies
    @ C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\HTTP\SN7VW\src\clientlayers\CookieRequest.jl:19 [inlined]
 [10] (::HTTP.HeadersRequest.var"#defaultheaders#2"{HTTP.HeadersRequest.var"#defaultheaders#1#3"{HTTP.CookieRequest.var"#managecookies#4"{HTTP.CookieRequest.var"#managecookies#1#5"{HTTP.RetryRequest.var"#manageretries#3"{HTTP.RetryRequest.var"#manageretries#1#4"{HTTP.ConnectionRequest.var"#connections#4"{HTTP.ConnectionRequest.var"#connections#1#5"{HTTP.TimeoutRequest.var"#timeouts#3"{HTTP.TimeoutRequest.var"#timeouts#1#4"{HTTP.ExceptionRequest.var"#exceptions#2"{HTTP.ExceptionRequest.var"#exceptions#1#3"{typeof(HTTP.StreamRequest.streamlayer)}}}}}}}}}}}})(req::HTTP.Messages.Request; iofunction::Nothing, decompress::Nothing, basicauth::Bool, detect_content_type::Bool, canonicalize_headers::Bool, kw::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Int64, Tuple{Symbol}, NamedTuple{(:verbose,), Tuple{Int64}}})
    @ HTTP.HeadersRequest C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\HTTP\SN7VW\src\clientlayers\HeadersRequest.jl:71
 [11] defaultheaders
    @ C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\HTTP\SN7VW\src\clientlayers\HeadersRequest.jl:14 [inlined]
 [12] (::HTTP.RedirectRequest.var"#redirects#3"{HTTP.RedirectRequest.var"#redirects#1#4"{HTTP.HeadersRequest.var"#defaultheaders#2"{HTTP.HeadersRequest.var"#defaultheaders#1#3"{HTTP.CookieRequest.var"#managecookies#4"{HTTP.CookieRequest.var"#managecookies#1#5"{HTTP.RetryRequest.var"#manageretries#3"{HTTP.RetryRequest.var"#manageretries#1#4"{HTTP.ConnectionRequest.var"#connections#4"{HTTP.ConnectionRequest.var"#connections#1#5"{HTTP.TimeoutRequest.var"#timeouts#3"{HTTP.TimeoutRequest.var"#timeouts#1#4"{HTTP.ExceptionRequest.var"#exceptions#2"{HTTP.ExceptionRequest.var"#exceptions#1#3"{typeof(HTTP.StreamRequest.streamlayer)}}}}}}}}}}}}}})(req::HTTP.Messages.Request; redirect::Bool, redirect_limit::Int64, redirect_method::Nothing, forwardheaders::Bool, response_stream::Nothing, kw::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Int64, Tuple{Symbol}, NamedTuple{(:verbose,), Tuple{Int64}}})
    @ HTTP.RedirectRequest C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\HTTP\SN7VW\src\clientlayers\RedirectRequest.jl:25
 [13] redirects
    @ C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\HTTP\SN7VW\src\clientlayers\RedirectRequest.jl:14 [inlined]
 [14] (::HTTP.MessageRequest.var"#makerequest#3"{HTTP.MessageRequest.var"#makerequest#1#4"{HTTP.RedirectRequest.var"#redirects#3"{HTTP.RedirectRequest.var"#redirects#1#4"{HTTP.HeadersRequest.var"#defaultheaders#2"{HTTP.HeadersRequest.var"#defaultheaders#1#3"{HTTP.CookieRequest.var"#managecookies#4"{HTTP.CookieRequest.var"#managecookies#1#5"{HTTP.RetryRequest.var"#manageretries#3"{HTTP.RetryRequest.var"#manageretries#1#4"{HTTP.ConnectionRequest.var"#connections#4"{HTTP.ConnectionRequest.var"#connections#1#5"{HTTP.TimeoutRequest.var"#timeouts#3"{HTTP.TimeoutRequest.var"#timeouts#1#4"{HTTP.ExceptionRequest.var"#exceptions#2"{HTTP.ExceptionRequest.var"#exceptions#1#3"{typeof(HTTP.StreamRequest.streamlayer)}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}})(method::String, url::URIs.URI, headers::Vector{Pair{String, String}}, body::Vector{UInt8}; copyheaders::Bool, response_stream::Nothing, http_version::HTTP.Strings.HTTPVersion, verbose::Int64, kw::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
    @ HTTP.MessageRequest C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\HTTP\SN7VW\src\clientlayers\MessageRequest.jl:35
 [15] makerequest
    @ C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\HTTP\SN7VW\src\clientlayers\MessageRequest.jl:24 [inlined]
 [16] request(stack::HTTP.MessageRequest.var"#makerequest#3"{HTTP.MessageRequest.var"#makerequest#1#4"{HTTP.RedirectRequest.var"#redirects#3"{HTTP.RedirectRequest.var"#redirects#1#4"{HTTP.HeadersRequest.var"#defaultheaders#2"{HTTP.HeadersRequest.var"#defaultheaders#1#3"{HTTP.CookieRequest.var"#managecookies#4"{HTTP.CookieRequest.var"#managecookies#1#5"{HTTP.RetryRequest.var"#manageretries#3"{HTTP.RetryRequest.var"#manageretries#1#4"{HTTP.ConnectionRequest.var"#connections#4"{HTTP.ConnectionRequest.var"#connections#1#5"{HTTP.TimeoutRequest.var"#timeouts#3"{HTTP.TimeoutRequest.var"#timeouts#1#4"{HTTP.ExceptionRequest.var"#exceptions#2"{HTTP.ExceptionRequest.var"#exceptions#1#3"{typeof(HTTP.StreamRequest.streamlayer)}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}, method::String, url::String, h::Vector{Pair{String, String}}, b::Vector{UInt8}, q::Nothing; headers::Vector{Pair{String, String}}, body::Vector{UInt8}, query::Nothing, kw::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
    @ HTTP C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\HTTP\SN7VW\src\HTTP.jl:457
 [17] request(stack::Function, method::String, url::String, h::Vector{Pair{String, String}}, b::Vector{UInt8}, q::Nothing)
    @ HTTP C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\HTTP\SN7VW\src\HTTP.jl:455
 [18] #request#20
    @ C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\HTTP\SN7VW\src\HTTP.jl:315 [inlined]
 [19] request
    @ C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\HTTP\SN7VW\src\HTTP.jl:313 [inlined]
 [20] request(method::String, url::String, h::Vector{Pair{String, String}})
    @ HTTP C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\HTTP\SN7VW\src\HTTP.jl:313
 [21] post(::String, ::Vararg{Any}; kw::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
    @ HTTP C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\HTTP\SN7VW\src\HTTP.jl:532
 [22] post(::String, ::Vararg{Any})
    @ HTTP C:\Users\TGebbels\.julia\packages\HTTP\SN7VW\src\HTTP.jl:532
 [23] top-level scope
    @ c:\Users\TGebbels\OneDrive - ...\HTTPsparql.jl:46
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

Replace `response = HTTP.post(url, ["query" => query])` with:

```
encoded_query = HTTP.escapeuri("query", query)
response = HTTP.post(url, ["Accept" => "application/sparql-results+json"], encoded_query; redirect_method = "POST")
```

### Explanation

#### Calling `HTTP.post` correctly

If you look up the [help](https://juliaweb.github.io/HTTP.jl/stable/reference/#HTTP.post) for `HTTP.post`, it shows the signature of the function as:

```
HTTP.post(url, headers, body; <keyword arguments>)
```

So, ChatGPT somehow has you sending your query information in the `headers` argument, whereas the [website](https://statistics.data.gov.uk/sparql) wants the query as part of the `body` i.e. the third argument:

> Issue a POST to the endpoint, with the query in the body, and an Accept header of sparql-results+json:

So the correct call would be `HTTP.post(url, ["Accept" => "application/sparql-results+json"], query)`. But this doesn't work and needs two more changes:

#### URL encoding the query

The website also says:

> with the query itself as a url-encoded parameter called query

so the query has to be first encoded using the `HTTP.escapeuri` function: `query_encoded = HTTP.escapeuri("query", query)`

#### Correct the redirection method

The website uses HTTP redirection to send the query to `https://statistics.data.gov.uk:443/sparql` - the specific URL doesn't matter, and HTTP.jl can handle the redirection, except that the server uses HTTP code `301` whereas they [should have used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76375107/8127) `308` to preserve the POST data. This makes HTTP.jl [change](https://github.com/JuliaWeb/HTTP.jl/issues/1074) the POST request to a GET, and discards the query data! Thankfully, we can force HTTP.jl to continue using POST after the redirection, with the keyword argument `redirect_method="POST"`.

Comment: Also, as a general comment, I'll say that ChatGPT is more likely to get things wrong than right, when it comes to Julia. If you have to use AI assistance, I'll recommend either Phind.com or JuliaHub's AskAI feature. Those aren't perfect, but they're much better than the basic free ChatGPT.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a full answer! The query does work now.